# how to get file last modified date?

Tags: c#, getfiles, fileversioninfo

I have one mistake .Why I dont know I want to take this file last modified date .but I have problem
[image]

in my code : date is coming always 01011601 why?Do you have any suggestions ?

[image]

File properties :
[image]

Comment: can you show the full list of attributes for file?

Comment: Is the file locked by some other application at this point? That's usually where I see this problem. Only difference is I would not expect that time...

Comment: I add file properties @BugFinder

Comment: I actually meant your file variable.. from this you would then probably have noticed no size, creation date etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the path you're getting your files from (`pthh`) is not the directory your app is running in, I would expect this date.
When you're calling `File.GetLastWriteTime(sqzfiles[i])` you are now relying on only the file name, so relative pathing is being used. Most likely, that file is not in your app's directory (although it **is** in `pthh`).

Since the file at the relative path does not exist, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx) will explain your unexpected date:

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

I've also seen this happen if the file is locked by another application, for what it's worth.

Comment: But if you use FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(UNCPathString); Console.WriteLine(string.Format("file {0} was updated on {1}:", fi.FullName, fi.LastWriteTime)); it finds the name but not the date. WTF.

Answer (score 2):

From msdn

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this
>   method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated
>   Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx

I guess your file is not found. Try to specify the full path of the file

Comment: thanks this is my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the file definitely exist when you try to access the write time?

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx) has the following remark:

> If the file described in the path parameter does not exist, this method returns 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), adjusted to local time.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it appears that your path may be invalid.  See MSDN documentation:

- [File.GetLastWriteTime Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can identify the source of the problem by creating a small test application (i.e. a [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development))) to verify that your code is working as expected.  To minimize potential errors, make the test as simple as possible (e.g. use hard coded file path).

### Additional Notes

- Speaking from experience, I know that the `GetLastWriteTime(...)` method does not always work as expected.  In certain situations, the method will not return an updated time-stamp even though the file has been modified/changed. This scenario is related to:

  - the type of lock(s) that have been applied to a file
  - the Windows disk driver that is being used